# how to replace next and prev to < and > in datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I want to change prev and next button with < and > this value.I see the **span class ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w and value is Prev** in inspect element.but i don't no where to change and how to change it.I have tried following but not working.

```
    <style>
     .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev .ui-icon{
            background: url("../../../Documents/ic_navigate_next_48px-128.png") ;
}

        .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next .ui-icon{
            background: url("../../../Documents/ic_navigate_next_48px-128.png") ;
            right: 2px;
        }    
    </style>
```

Comment: Contain your datepicker in a custom ID or class, then change the background on the .ui-icon class: #my-calendar-id .ui-datepicker-next .ui-icon  {background:url('my_image'); }

Comment: Sorry for mistake in uploading code.

Answer (score 0):

Give your datepicker element your own class or ID. And change the next and previous button as follow by overriding default CSS of datepicker dialog.

```
<style>
     .yourClass.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev .ui-icon{
          /* Your code here */     
      }

      /* OR */

      #yourID.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev .ui-icon{
          /* Your code here */     
      }
</style>
```

Comment: <input type="text" name="f1" required id="date1_live"   placeholder="Select From Date" class="from_date"  >   <script>
         $("#date1_live").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
                        showAnim:'slideDown',
                        dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy'
        });      
      </script>

Comment: I think you've not added the jquery UI css as it shows arrows in dialog by default. https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
 .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev .ui-icon { background-image:none !important; }

 .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next .ui-icon { background-image:none !important; } 

 .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev .ui-icon:before { content:"<"; }

 .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next .ui-icon:before { content:">"; }       
</style>
```